# Why is the anything below my "content" class faded on the active column?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if anyone could give me an explanation on why anything below my "content" class in each column is faded? I would like it so that everything in the active column is visible (works to an extent) and everything in the non active columns is faded.

Live Test Version:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gc68V/

Here's the HTML:

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="header-bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>| Dare.me |</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="leaderboard.html">Leaderboard</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--header-bar-->

    <div class="columns">
        <div id="left-column">
            <p class="title left">Easy</p>
            <p class="content">Feeling like a whimp?<br/> 
            Take one of our easy dares.</p>

            <div class="circle-text"><div><a href="php/easy.php">Click <span class="bold">Here</span> For An Easy Dare</a></div></div>

            <div id="test"><p>Test Text</p></div>

        </div><!--left-column-->

        <div id="centre-column">
            <p class="title centre">Medium</p>
            <p class="content">Feeling adventurous<br /> 
            are we?</p>

            <div class="circle-text"><div><a href="php/medium.php">Click <span class="bold">Here</span> For A Medium Dare</a></div></div>

        </div><!--centre-column--> 

        <div id="right-column">
            <p class="title right">Hard</p>
            <p class="content">Feeling lucky?<br />
            prepare yourself!</p>

            <div class="circle-text"><div><a href="php/hard.php">Click <span class="bold">Here</span> For A Hard Dare</a></div></div>

        </div><!--right-column-->
    </div><!--columns-->
 </div><!--container-->
```

& here's the CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

    /* Fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'code_boldregular';
    src: url('../fonts/code_bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/code_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/code_bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/code_bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/code_bold-webfont.svg#code_boldregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'code_lightregular';
    src: url('../fonts/code_light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/code_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/code_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/code_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/code_light-webfont.svg#code_lightregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

    /* Body & Container Styling */

body{
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

    /* Header Bar Styling */

#header-bar{
    height: 50px;
    width: 218px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header-bar ul{
    padding-top: 19px;
}

#header-bar li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#header-bar p{
    font-family: 'code_boldregular';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #414141;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#header-bar a{
    font-family: 'code_lightregular';
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #898989;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#header-bar a:hover{
    color: #c0392b;
}

    /* Column Holder & Hover Effect Styling */

div[id$="column"]{
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;     
}

.columns{
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.columns:hover div{  
    transition: opacity linear .2s;    
    opacity:0.3;
}

div[id$="column"]:hover{
    transition: border ease-out .1s,margin ease-out .1s,padding ease-out .1s;
    z-index:200;
    margin-left:-20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    border-right:solid 20px;
    opacity:1;
}

    /* Column Styling */

#left-column{
    background-color: #27ae60;
    left:0;
    border-color:#27ae60;    
}

#centre-column{
    background-color: #e67e22;
    left: 33.33%;
    border-color:#e67e22;
}

#right-column{
    background-color: #c0392b;
    left: 66.66%;
    border-color:#c0392b;
}

    /* Column Text Styling */

.title{
    font-family: 'code_boldregular';
    font-size: 120px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 82px;
    text-align: center;
}   

.title.left{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #2ecc71;
}

.title.centre{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #d35400;
}

.title.right{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #e74c3c;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
   .title { font-size: 100px; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
   .title { font-size: 80px; }
}

.content{
    font-family: 'code_lightregular';
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 16px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
   .content { font-size: 30px; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
   .content { font-size: 24px; }
}


.test-link{
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.test-link a{
    font-family: 'code_lightregular';
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
        color: #fff;
}

.bold{
    font-family: 'code_boldregular';
}

.circle-text {
    width:50%;
}
.circle-text:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background: #4679BD; 
    -moz-border-radius: 50%; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-text div{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you write...

```
.columns:hover div{  
  transition: opacity linear .2s;    
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

...your saying fade every `<div>` that is a child of `.columns`.

You probably want the direct child CSS selector:

```
.columns:hover > div{  
  transition: opacity linear .2s;    
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Gc68V/1/**